# SharePoint Online (O365): For a document library, how can I set different retention period for each document?

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention

SharePoint Online (O365): 
For a document library, how can I set the different retention period for each document?

For Example:

```
One document should be deleted after: Created + 1 year = Annually,
The second document should be deleted: after Created + 4 months = Quarterly,
The third document should be deleted: after Created + 1 month = Monthly.
```

Note:
There is a field in document library name Retention Period with values Annually, quarterly and monthly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information management policies work based on date fields. So you would need to date column that contains the document deletion date in your case. Here is one approach.

1. Create a column in the library (or content type if available) called 'Deletion Date'
2. Build a workflow that runs on item updated to calculate 'Deletion Date' based on your logic. The workflow would be a simple if else condition that checks the value of the column 'Retention Period' in your case and updates the 'Deletion Date' accordingly.
3. Add a information management policy on the library or content type with a condition 'Deletion Date' + 0 Days and action as 'Move to Recycle Bin'. This option is available on content type settings as well as library settings.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it through Content Type and Information Management Policy.

Here are the steps:
Under List Setting for the Document Library - Click Information Management Policy
[image]

You can have the **content types for your document one, two and three** (perhaps, invoice, contracts, customer and set the retention separately: 
[image]

Click the Content Type - My Custom Document and Enable Retention 
[image]

You can define retention and move to recycle bin
[image]